Three-blade propeller balancing
I'm balancing a three-blade propeller.  The propellers weigh exactly the same to the 10th of a gram. When I place it on shaft with a very sensitive wheel bearing, one of the blades always moved downward.

I've posted an answer based on my guess of your question, but this post can be improved by asking a question.

What's the question?

The most likely reasons you are experiencing this:

The shaft is not exactly at the center of the propeller.
The length of the propellers is slightly different.
The density of the propellers is not uniform.  Even though they weigh the same, they are distributing that weight unequally.
If the movement downward is visible while the prop is spinning, then the pitch of the propellers may not be exactly equal.

